# How to ensure data is eventually written to two Azure blobs?

Tags: algorithm, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, distributed-computing, azure-service-fabric

I'm designing a multi-tenant Azure Service Fabric application in which we'll be storing event data in Azure Append-Only blobs.

There'll be two kinds of blobs; *merge blobs* (one per tenant); and  *instance blobs* (one for each "object" owned by a tenant - there'll be 100K+ of these per tenant)

There'll be a single writer per *instance blob*. This writer keeps track of the last written blob position and can thereby ensure (using conditional writes) that no other writer has written to the blob since the last successful write. This is an important aspect that we'll use to provide strong consistency per instance.

However, all writes to an *instance blob* **must** also *eventually* (but as soon as possible) reach the single (per tenant) *merge blob*.

Under normal operation I'd like these merge writes to take place within ~100 ms.

My question is about how we best should implement this guaranteed double-write feature:

> The implementation must guarantee that data written to an instance blob **will eventually** also be written to the corresponding merge blob **exactly once**.

The following inconsistencies must be avoided:

1. Data is successfully written to an *instance blob* but never written to the corresponding *merge blob*.
2. Data is written more than once to the *merge blob*.

Answer (score 0):

Most easiest way as for me is to use events: Service Bus or Event Hubs or any other provider to guaranty that an event will be stored and reachable at least somewhere. Plus, it will give a possibility to write events to Blob Storage in batches. Also, I think it will significantly reduce pressure on Service Fabric and will allow to process events at desired timing.
So you could have a lot of Stateless Services or just Web Workers that will pick up new messages from a queue and in batch send them to a Statefull Service.
Let's say that it will be a Merge service. You would need to partition these services and the best way to send a batch of events grouped by one partition is to make such Stateless Service or Web Worker.

Than you can have a separate Statefull Actor for each object. But on your place I would try to create 100k actors or any other real workload and see how expensive it would be. If it is too expensive and you cannot afford such machines, then everything could be handled in another partitioned Stateless Service.

Okay, now we have the next scheme: something puts logs into ESB, something peaks these evetns from ESB in batches or very frequently, handling transactions and processing errors. After that something peaks bunch of events from a queue, it sends it to a particular Merge service that stores data in its state and calls particular actor to do the same thing.

Once actor writes its data to its state and service does the same, then such sevent in ESB can be marked as processed and removed from the queue. Then you just need to write stored data from Merge service and actors to Blob storage once in a while.

If actor is unable to store event, then operation is not complete and Merge service should not store data too. If Blob storage is unreachable for actors or Merge services, it will become reachable in the future and logs will be stored as they are saved in state or at least they could be retrieved from actors/service manually.

If Merge service is unreachable, I would store such event in a [poison message queue](https://www.google.com/search?q=poison+message+queue&ie=UTF-8&gws_rd=cr&fg=1) for later processing, or try to write logs directly to Blob storage but it is a little bit dangerous though chances to write at that moment only to one kind of storage are pretty low.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Stateful Actor for this. You won't need to worry about concurrency, because there is none. In the state of the Actor you can keep track of which operations were successfully completed. (write 1, write 2)

Still, writing 'exactly once' in a distributed system (without a DTC) is never 100% waterproof.

Some more info about that:

- [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416551/why-is-exactly-once-semantics-infeasible)
- [link](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjFy6zY8vLPAhXHIMAKHWzsBHkQFghQMAg&url=http%3A%2F%2Filpubs.stanford.edu%3A8090%2F483%2F1%2F2000-7.pdf)